# What file formats does lp support?

Tags: printing

What types of files, such as images (jpg, png, tiff) and documents (pdf, doc, docx, xls) can `lp` render correctly and print?  I'm trying to make a print kiosk and don't quite know how accommodating I can be with `lp` to print from the command line with a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lp` (/`lpr`) can only print PDF, p(ost)s(ript), and plain text files.

---

But this does not has to stop here: you can make PDFs with a lot of tools and then print that PDF.

Examples:

- If you want docx and other Microsoft formats you can use a converter like [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) to convert those to PDF.
- For images you can do the same: make a PDF from the image and print that:

  ```
  mogrify -format pdf *.jpg
  ```

  will create a PDF from jpgs.
- Or with the convert command in imagemagick:

  ```
  for file in *.jpg ; do convert "$file" "${file/%jpg/pdf}" ; done
  ```